# Creating multiple instances of a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below is the source code of a simple parallax plugin:

```
/*
Plugin: jQuery Parallax
Version 1.1.3
Author: Ian Lunn
Twitter: @IanLunn
Author URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/
Plugin URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/

(function( $ ){
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowHeight = $window.height();

    $window.resize(function () {
        windowHeight = $window.height();
    });

    $.fn.parallax = function(xpos, speedFactor, outerHeight) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var getHeight;
        var firstTop;
        var paddingTop = 0;

        //get the starting position of each element to have parallax applied to it
        $this.each(function(){
            firstTop = $this.offset().top;
        });

        if (outerHeight) {
            getHeight = function(jqo) {
                return jqo.outerHeight(true);
            };
        } else {
            getHeight = function(jqo) {
                return jqo.height();
            };
        }

        // setup defaults if arguments aren't specified
        if (arguments.length < 1 || xpos === null) xpos = "50%";
        if (arguments.length < 2 || speedFactor === null) speedFactor = 0.1;
        if (arguments.length < 3 || outerHeight === null) outerHeight = true;

        // function to be called whenever the window is scrolled or resized
        function update(){
            var pos = $window.scrollTop();
            $this.each(function(){
                var $element = $(this);
                var top = $element.offset().top;
                var height = getHeight($element);

                // Check if totally above or totally below viewport
                if (top + height < pos || top > pos + windowHeight) {
                    return;
                }

        console.log(firstTop + " " + pos);

                $this.css('backgroundPosition', xpos + " " + Math.round((firstTop - pos) * speedFactor) + "px");
            });
        }

        $window.bind('scroll', update).resize(update);
        update();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now suppose i call the plugin , like so , on multiple elements.

```
$('#intro').parallax("50%", .8);
$('#second').parallax("50%", 0.1);
$('.bg').parallax("50%", 0.4);
$('#third').parallax("50%", 0.3);
```

What am i really doing ? creating multiple instances of the plugin ?

A demo of the plugin itself can be seen **[HERE](http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/)**.

Comment: Your "plugin" is not a plugin as it stands. It does not appear to retain any instance information (usually on the data() of the element). What you seem to have is a basic jquery extension method. Are you having trouble with it updating separate elements?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie , No , i have no trouble , was just curious , about the following http://chopapp.com/#exg6lhqe

Comment: Calling `.parallax()` invokes the `$.fn.parallax` method, to which you have the complete source code. Which part of it do you think would "create multiple instances" of itself? What would that even mean?

Comment: Really not clear what you are even asking

Comment: well some plugins use the new keyword internally and every-time they get called on an element , a new instance is created . right ? , is the same happening in the above plugin too ?

Comment: Do you see the `new` keyword anywhere?

Comment: @Juhana , Not in the plugin , no i did't , But when `$.fn.parallax` is a new instance being created (inside jquery) .

Comment: if you aren't having a problem then this question really belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @charlietfl No it does't ! because i am having a problem understanding the code

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik _"What am i really doing ? creating multiple instances of the plugin ?"_ Appear to be creating single instance of plugin for each element `'#intro'` , `'#second'` , `'.bg'` , `'#third'` where `.parallax()` called on ?

Comment: @charlietfl this absolutely is not a question for code review. Questions on CodeReview have 3 main requirements: 1) the code is the OP's, 2) The code is functional, 3) The code is embedded in the question.

This would immediately fail on point 1)  

In addition, questions about understanding code are also off-topic for CodeReview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are not creating multiple instances of the plugin.

What you are doing is that you are calling this function multiple times:

```
$.fn.parallax = function(xpos, speedFactor, outerHeight) {
```

This is perfectly fine to do.

Comment: "perfectly fine"?. Surely wasting time repeatedly calling redundant operations is not "perfectly fine". I think you meant it had *no obvious side-effects* :)

Answer (score 1):

What you really are looking at is a jQuery extension method. This method merges the contents of an object onto the jQuery prototype to provide new jQuery instance methods.
Whenever you see the `fn` property, you are looking at an alias to the prototype property of jQuery.

Lets examine some lines in the parallax script you are embedding:

```
$.fn.parallax = function(xpos, speedFactor, outerHeight) {
```

This line is the start of a new jQuery prototype extension method that takes three arguments

Here is a more simple example that extends jQuery with a new method

```
$(function () {
    // declare the new method greenify
    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        // The element that this method is used on will have the color green by using jQuery .css();
        this.css( "color", "green" );
    };

    // Then to use your brand new jQuery extension method simply do this
    $( "a" ).greenify();
    $('.myElem').greenify();
    $('#someElemId').greenify();

});
```

What is happening is that we are using the same method and applying it to different elements in the dom.

I hope this made it clearer what is really going on and how extension methods work.

Comment: Based on your question it did not seem like you did since you clearly ask if you are creating multiple instances, but what you really do is running the same extension method several times on different elements.